# I want to play electric guitar, but should I start with acoustic?

Tags: guitar, learning, self-learning

I'm 17, and I really want to learn guitar and drums, but for now I want to start with guitar. I have always loved the sound and style of the electric, but I have already played around with a acoustic. I want to know if it would be better to learn acoustic and move to electric, or just start with electric. I used to play trombone, so I can read music, and I plan to teach myself, not get lessons.

Comment: Yes, you can start without acoustic guitar.

Answer (score 7):

There is an advantage to starting on whatever type of guitar interests you the most. If electric guitar is of the most interest to you, that is a good place to start. If you just have no interest in acoustic music, I would suggest starting with an electric.

There are also advantages to starting with acoustic guitar. You will develop stamina faster by playing acoustic. Acoustic guitar is less forgiving of poor technique, which is not a bad thing in the beginning. It is easier to haul an acoustic guitar around to play for friends and family (which they might view as a disadvantage, for a while), or easy to haul around for impromptu jam circles. Any time you can get playing for or with others is very valuable.

Of course you can learn without a teacher, and having already had lessons on another instrument will be helpful, but it would really speed things along to get a good teacher in the beginning, at least for a little while. A good teacher can help you identify technical problems and correct them before they become bad habits, and can help you to maximize your practice time.

Answer (score 2):

Go straight to electric. It will need you to buy other parts of the kit - an amp., lead, etc., but that's maybe the reason so many start with acoustic. Convenience, as David says, and obviously expense, as a cheap acoustic will often come along at far less than a cheap electric with accoutrements.

It's easier to play an electric, if it's well set up, and far more fun sounds can be made to emanate! If you're serious about playing, it's worth getting a half decent guitar - Epiphone, Yamaha, Squier, Vintage are examples that will do for several years.

There are advantages in owning both - if the opportunity arises, take it. One on its own can't do both jobs.

You'll get along fine without a teacher, having some musical background, but it's worth while popping to see one every so often, just to check you out.

Answer (score 1):

An acoustic guitar will give you a pure sound and you will be able to recognize the notes and notice your mistakes much better. It is more challenging to sound amazing with a acoustic guitar but when you do it shows how well you have master guitar.

When you say "the sound of an electric guitar", it's not to specific as fenders sound different that gibsons and on top of that you can add distortion, delay, chorus, and much more.

And At some point, playing with a electric guitar you will want to play an acoustic so might as well have both. further more there is classic guitars as well (nylon strings).

Answer (score 0):

I chose my first guitar by the way the neck felt in my hand when I played it. It was well set up and played very easily when I made chords. It was an Epiphone Emperor arch-top with F-holes but it was also electric so I could plug it in when I had access to an amplifier. I had the option of playing it acoustically or amplified, and as a beginner, I played it acoustically. When I finally got an amp, the transition to electric was quick and easy, and it opened a whole new chapter in my musical development. So... that's one way you can go!

Answer (score 0):

No. If you start with the instrument you 'want to play' you will more likely stick with it.